# I need to expand my root partition by deleting another partition apparently not in use

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

This is a screen shot of my `gparted`:

[image]

I am new to Linux. I had a `d:\` drive on my Windows machine which I intended to use for Linux but during installation failed to create a root partition.. ended up shrinking `C:` too create the root partition. I thought my `d:\` (`/dev/sda4`) would be my `/home` but only realized it wasn't, so when I was getting space errors.

I therefore need to either:

- delete `/dev/sda4` and extend `/dev/sda3`
- or move my `/home` to `/dev/sda4` so that I have space for `/root`. possibly extend /root as well for future growth.

Comment: **Not to take anything away from anybody else**... but I'm a little hurt... you followed my advice... and my lengthy and detailed steps... but I didn't get your accept vote :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first doing any operation on a mounted disk can cause errors.
boot from a live CD or an external drive with linux on it.

## option 1:

use gparted to delete sda4. then grow sda3 and sda5 to fill the free space.

you will get a warning about moving the root partition causing boot errors.
this can be ignored because you aren't moving the files just growing the end.

## option 2, separate home folder:

record the uuid of the sda4 for the next step.

edit /etc/fstab to add the lines:

> #/home
>
> UUID=(the uuid of sda4)   /home      ext4   defaults    0   2

rename /home folder to /homeback. and make a new folder /home.

copy everything from /homeback to the new partition

reboot your computer. if everything mounts correctly. you can delete /homeback

as mentioned above, it would be a good idea to add a 3 GB swap partition. instead of using a swapfile. this should be placed after  sda5 and before the partition for home.

Comment: You can't resize sda5 unless you resize sda3 first.

Comment: I have gone with option 1 from ravery. the movements worked. Thanks! I had been using a swap partition but had removed it so I recreated it and followed heynnema but when I do a swapon I am getting "Device or resource busy"

Comment: I did a restart and ran swapon again and now when I do sysinfo, linux-swap is recognised. Thank you ravery. Thank you heynnema. Problem solved

Answer (score 1):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important Ubuntu files, as this procedure can corrupt or loose data.

---

**Note:** because of the size of your HDD, I don't recommend creating a separate /home in sda4.

The use of an extended partition (sda3) makes this a little difficult. I'll outline the easiest way first, and we can add more to the procedure if we have to.

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower part of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

---

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- right-click on sda4 in the lower pane and **delete** it
- right-click on sda3 in the lower pane and **resize** it all the way to the right
- right-click on the unallocated space in sda3 and create an appropriate swap partition
- if need be, right-click on the new swap partition and select `swapoff`
- right-click on the swap partition and **move** it all way to the right
- right-click on sda5 and **resize** it all the way to the right
- reboot
- in `terminal`...

  - `sudo blkid` # note the UUID for the swap partition
  - `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`

Add these lines, changing the UUID with the one from the blkid command...

```
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=071f8b0e-8e16-4f4d-90ff-a4ae9cc56e2b  none  swap   sw    0    0
```

- still in `terminal`...

  - save the file and quit gedit
  - `swapon -a`
  - quit the terminal
- reboot and confirm operation with `free -h` and `swapon` commands

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60913/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-i-need-to-expand-my-root-partition-by-deleting).